# Inconsistency in data storage when method call is asynchronous(@Async) in spring hibernate project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a method annotated with spring @Async annotation(Also **No** @Transactional annotation is there on this method).

I had put @Transactional on the method being invoked by this method in different class.

All the read call performs pretty well but write call are **not** consistent. And also i don't see any error whenever hibernate call does not save and neither it rollback.

Glimpse of code i wrote:

```
Class CallbackService{
....

@Async
public void processCallback(...){
myService.performTask(...);
...
}
}
Class MyService{

@Transactional
public void performTask(){
.....//read-call //working as expected

mydao.saveOrUpdate(...);// write call. Inconsistent. Fails randomly

....//Other task performs well
}
}
```

Any help will appreciated. I am stuck on this for 2 days now.I have tried various answer found online and nothing works. It still fails randomly. Please let me know if you need anything else

Comment: Please post the stack traces you get on failure. You can of course edit out package names to hide sensitive details, but it is nice to know the errors including any root cause exceptions and the stack traces.

Comment: Did you tried `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`?

Comment: I tried @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) but it does not solve the problem and there is no error thrown. It even prints the log after it but does not save them in DB

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not in in async. Problem in fact that you allow to read and write without locks by multiple threads. You need to lock your read record before update. But with insert all much worse, because you need to lock whole table for inserts to prevent double insert.

Try to read about pessimistic locks and table locks

Comment: Thanks for reply. The same thing works flawlessly when @Async is removed so I can assure you this has something to do with async

Comment: are you sure that when you remove `@Async` you send multiple requests/multiple method call in different threads. Also you said that randomly - that means that if you tried once and all ok - it's means nothing

Comment: Yes i have observed the behaviour for days.. when in async 10 cases per 50 are failing and when called without it. Everything works fine. This is method is been hit more than 200 times a day.. Thats why I m certain